# Create Array of Dates from JSON

Tags: swift, date, jsondecoder, enumerated

I would like to create an array of dates (or of tuples including an index and a data) from the following JSON.

My code is creating an array but instead of creating an array of dates, it breaks up the dates into characters. What do I need to do to create an array just of dates.

JSON looks like:

```
let json = """
    [{"date":"2017-01-05",
     "price":119.34},{"date":"2017-01-06",
     "price":118.93}];
```

Code is:

```
let myprices = try JSONDecoder().decode([Prices].self, from: Data(json.utf8))
let dates = myprices.sorted{$0.date < $1.date}.enumerated().map {Array($0.element.date)}
```

Code prints to console as:

dates [["2", "0", "1", "7", "-", "0", "1", "-", "0", "5"], ["2", "0", "1", "7", "-", "0", "1", "-", "0", "6"], ["2", "0", "1", "7", "-", "0", "1", "-", "0"]]

Thanks in advance for any suggestions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace

```
let dates = myprices.sorted{$0.date < $1.date}.enumerated().map {Array($0.element.date)}
```

with

```
let dates = myprices.sorted{$0.date < $1.date}.map { $0.date }
```

Currently you may be making `let data:String` change it to `let date:Date` and supply a formatter to the decoder check [This](https://useyourloaf.com/blog/swift-codable-with-custom-dates/)

Comment: Yes. This fixed the problem. Thanks for tip about date decoding. In this case, I am decoding date as a string  let date: String which I think this is okay because I am using date as a label--not doing any date calculations